# Determining the Epoch Number with tf.train.string_input_producer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, queue, epoch

I have some doubts on how `tf.train.string_input_producer` works. So suppose I fed filename_list as an input parameter to the `string_input_producer`. Then, according to the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data, this will create a `FIFOQueue`, where I can set epoch number, shuffle the file names and so on. Therefore, in my case, I have 4 file names ("db1.tfrecords", "db2.tfrecords"...). And I used `tf.train.batch` to feed the network batch of images. In addition, each file_name/database, contain a set of images for one person. The second database is for the second person and so on. So far I have the following code:

```
tfrecords_filename_seq = [(common + "P16_db.tfrecords"), (common + "P17_db.tfrecords"), (common + "P19_db.tfrecords"),
                          (common + "P21_db.tfrecords")]

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tfrecords_filename_seq, num_epochs=num_epoch, shuffle=False, name='queue')
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

key, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
    features={
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'annotation_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    })

image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)

image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

annotation = tf.cast(features['annotation_raw'], tf.string)

min_after_dequeue = 100
num_threads = 4
capacity = min_after_dequeue + num_threads * batch_size
label_batch, images_batch = tf.train.batch([annotation, image],
                                                        shapes=[[], [112, 112, 3]],
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        capacity=capacity,
                                                        num_threads=num_threads)
```

Finally, when trying to view out the reconstructed image at the output of the autoencoder, I got the first the images from the 1st database, then I start viewing images from the second database and so on.

My question: How can i know if I'm within the same epoch? And if I'm within the sane epoch, how can i merge a batch of images from all the file_names that I have?

Finally, I tried to print out the value of the epoch by evaluating the local variable within the `Session` as follows:

```
epoch_var = tf.local_variables()[0]
```

Then:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(epoch_var.eval())) # Here I got 9 as output. don't know y.
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: You can count the number of records using `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator` and given the batch size, you should get the current epoch number. Didn't get your second question though.

Comment: @vijaym, this is not what I am asking about. I have `tf.train.string_input_producer` and not `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I figured out is that using `tf.train.shuffle_batch_join` solves my issue as it starts shuffling images from different data sets. In other words, every batch is now containing images from all the datasets/file_names. Here is an example:

```
def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    key, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={
            'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'annotation_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })

    # This is how we create one example, that is, extract one example from the database.
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    # The height and the weights are used to
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)

    # The image is reshaped since when stored as a binary format, it is flattened. Therefore, we need the
    # height and the weight to restore the original image back.
    image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

    annotation = tf.cast(features['annotation_raw'], tf.string)
    return annotation, image

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_threads, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=num_epoch, shuffle=False,
                                                    name='queue')
    # Therefore, Note that here we have created num_threads readers to read from the filename_queue.
    example_list = [read_my_file_format(filename_queue=filename_queue) for _ in range(num_threads)]
    min_after_dequeue = 100
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + num_threads * batch_size
    label_batch, images_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch_join(example_list,
                                                            shapes=[[], [112, 112, 3]],
                                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                                            capacity=capacity,
                                                            min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return label_batch, images_batch, example_list

label_batch, images_batch, input_ann_img = \
    input_pipeline(tfrecords_filename_seq, batch_size, num_threads, num_epochs=num_epoch)
```

And now this is going to create a number of readers to read from the `FIFOQueue`, and after each reader will have a different decoder. Finally, after decoding the images, they will fed into another `Queue` that is created after calling `tf.train.shuffle_batch_join` to feed the network a batch of images.